# Python Bitwise ~ Operator

Tags: python, tilde

Several previously asked questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113093/bitwise-operator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177002/bitwise-operators-in-python) mention only why this happens i.e. 2's compliment.
I need help with how to convert this :

```
print("if ~(0b11011111) is "+str(bin(~(0b1101111))) +" not 0b00100000")
print("and ~(0b00100000) is  " +str(bin(~(0b00100000)))+" not 11011111")
```

Output :

```
if ~(0b11011111) is -0b1110000 not 0b00100000
and ~(0b00100000) is  -0b100001 not 11011111
```

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Daweo I worked on bitwise operator for Arduino project based on Arduino C. using same ~ operator. It was long ago but I remember it was the same way. Now I was writing code in Python it just not working showing negative values. I look for unsigned int in python I couldn't understand much about it. Its seems like in examples they are squaring the number to achieve in.

Comment: I believe there a way to do it with unsigned definition but not 100% sure

Comment: I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python

Comment: if I only have 8 bits, is there any better way than this `0x100+~(0b00100000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a fixed number of bits, inverting them is easy — just invert them. So, for example, it we are working with 4-bit integers, the inverse of  5 (0b0101) is 0b1010

However, Python has arbitrary-sized integers, which makes things a bit tricker. If we invert 5 (0b101), is the result 1010 or 11111010 or 1111111111111010 or what? So Python [defines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) inverting in terms of integers (in the mathematical sense, as opposed to strings of bits); `~x ≝ -(x+1)`. Why this definition? When working with two’s-complement representation of negatives, `neg(x) = inv(x)+1` so it makes sense that `inv(x) = neg(x)-1 = -(x+1)`. This is why `~5` comes out to `-6`.

So that is why you are getting negative numbers, but how do you get the positive value that you expect? The language spec does not say it explicitly, but the bitwise `&` and `|` operators seem to treat negatives as having “enough” ones on the left. This means that if you mask out only as many bits to the right as you want, you get a positive number. For example, if we want to invert a 4-bit number 5, we can do `bin(~0b101 & 0b1111` and get the expected `0b1010`.

You seem to be expecting 8-bit numbers, so for example `bin(~0b00100000 & 0xff)` gives you `0b11011111`.